# Delphi XE8 idHttp Erromessage text coding is wrong

Tags: delphi, text, put, idhttp

I am using Delphi XE8 and I am sendig a PUT message via idHttp.

```
  Http.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
  Http.Request.BasicAuthentication := false;
  http.Request.Method := 'PUT';
  Http.Request.Accept := '*/*';
  Http.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('apiKey','T_API23207_169');
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('transactionId','20200924_015');
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('usziID','1');
  Http.Request.AcceptEncoding := '*';
  http.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';

  kuldes_header.Text := http.Request.CustomHeaders.Text;

  http.Intercept := IdLogEvent1;
  IdLogEvent1.Active := true;

  jsonToSend := TStringStream.create(json_adat.Text,system.sysUtils.TEncoding.UTF8);

  kuldes_body.Lines.LoadFromStream(jsonToSend);

  try
    try
        send_text := http.Put('http://10.109.132.24:8090/rest/usziIroda/1',jsonToSend);
        resp := http.ResponseText;
        code := http.ResponseCode;
        jsonToSend.Position := 0;
    except
        on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
          begin
          code := e.ErrorCode;
          error_message := e.ErrorMessage;
          end;
    end;

    hiba_kod.Lines.Add(IntToStr(code));
    valasz_uzenet.Text := send_text;
    hiba_uzenet.Text := error_message;   enter code here
```

The returned error message has strange characters:
"Megadott tranzakciÃ³ azonosÃ­tÃ³val mÃ¡r tÃ¶rtÃ©nt API hÃ­vÃ¡s"

But it should be like this:
"Megadott tranzakció azonosí­tóval már történt API hí­vás"

How can I convert the returned message to normal string?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the issue get resolved if you change `Http.Request.AcceptEncoding := '*'` to `'utf-8'` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you showed - `Megadott tranzakciÃ³ azonosÃ­tÃ³val mÃ¡r tÃ¶rtÃ©nt API hÃ­vÃ¡s` - is the UTF-8 encoded form of `Megadott tranzakció azonosí­tóval már történt API hí­vás` being misinterpreted in Latin-1/ISO-8859-1.  Which most likely means that the response did not specify a UTF-8 charset in its `Content-Type` header (since you have an `Intercept` assigned, you can easily verify this for yourself), so Indy would fall back to a default charset instead.

The original UTF-8 bytes have been decoded and lost before you can access the response data in `send_text` or `error_message`.  However, since ISO-8859-1 basically has a 1:1 relationship between byte values and Unicode codepoint values, what you can try doing in this specific situation is copy the `ErrorMessage`'s `Char` values *as-is* to a `RawByteString(65001)` or `UTF8String`, and then let the RTL decode that as UTF-8 back into a proper UTF-16 `(Unicode)String`, eg:

```pascal
function DecodeISO88591AsUTF8(const S: string): string;
var
  utf8: UTF8String;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(utf8, Length(S));
  for I := Low(S) to High(S) do
    utf8[I] := AnsiChar(S[I]);
  Result := string(utf8);
end;

...

error_message := e.ErrorMessage;
//if not TextIsSame(http.Response.CharSet, 'utf-8') then
if TextIsSame(http.Response.CharSet, 'ISO-8859-1') then
  error_message := DecodeISO88591AsUTF8(error_message);
```

Alternatively, you can instead call the overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Put()` that fills a response `TStream` instead of returning a decoded `String`, and then you can decode the original raw bytes however you want.  Just be sure to enable the `hoNoProtocolErrorException` and `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` flags in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property so that any error response is stored in the `TStream`, then you don't need a `try/except` to handle the `EIdHTTPProtocolException` separately.

```pascal
http.HTTPOptions := http.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];

...

RespStrm := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  http.Put('http://10.109.132.24:8090/rest/usziIroda/1', jsonToSend, RespStrm);
  resp := http.ResponseText;
  code := http.ResponseCode;
  jsonToSend.Position := 0;
  RespStrm.Position := 0;

  if (code div 100) = 2 then
  begin
    send_text := decode RespStrm as needed...;
  end else
  begin
    error_message := decode RespStrm as needed...;
  end;
finally
  RespStrm.Free;
end;

...
```